# Getting error when implementing YouTube authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

```
var readline = require('readline');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'];
```

Getting the error:

```
{google} = require('googleapis') SyntaxError: 
Unexpected token {
```

I am using [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs).

Comment: So why is your `google` variable wrapped in curly brackets?

Comment: I Think they've made a mistake because there is in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you using? Make sure you're running up-to-date node. This is just modern js syntax for getting function(s) out of a module.

Answer (score 0):

It's solve using by older version of googleapis.

here link:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases/tag/23.0.0

command : npm install googleapis@23.0.0